# NeoVim FZF Hidden Files

Tags: bash

Hello bash experts out there,

I'm new to using neovim and I'm having a hard time figuring out why my FZF is not showing hidden files, such as `.gitignore` and `.htaccess``

Here's what I have currently in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:fzf_action = { 'enter': 'tab split' }
let g:fzf_height = '25%'
map <leader>t :FZF --reverse<cr>
```

I've looked at the [github issue](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/337) and I didn't really understand what to do with the command they used.

> Got it. Needed to add the --hidden flag.

I've tried to add the hidden flag by doing:

```
map <leader>t :FZF --reverse --hidden<cr>
```

But it returns an error saying `error runnning --expect=enter`...

I've also tried adding this:

> let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'ag --hidden --ignore .git -l ""'

But after adding this, whenever I run the command, it's always returning a `0/0 no result found` no matter what I type, even if the search is empty.

Comment: You should use `-g` instead of `-l`. Try this `let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'ag --hidden --ignore .git -g ""'`

Comment: @nima I've tried the command you've sent and the result is the same. Whenever I run the command, it's returning `0/0 no result found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in bash:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="find . -path '*/\.*' -type d -prune -o -type f -print -o -type l -print 2> /dev/null | sed s/^..//"
```

This should resolve the problem with dot files not being found, but files inside any hidden directory (for example files inside `.git` or `.svn` directories) are still ignored.
If you need to list files inside hidden directories too (which you probably don't) try this:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="find . -type f -print -o -type l -print 2> /dev/null | sed s/^..//"
```

Then `fzf` should work the way you want it to.

Comment: Can you tell me how would I ignore file like `.DS_Store`? I've tried adding `-not -name '.DS_Store'` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is important where you add new conditions. If you need to `prune` .DS_Store as well as other dot files, one way is to add `-o -name .DS_Store` before `-prune` so the final export command (based on first command in the answer) would be `export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="find . -path '*/\.*' -type d -o -name .DS_Store -prune -o -type f -print -o -type l -print 2> /dev/null | sed s/^..//"`

Comment: I've tried to add the `-o -name .DS_Store` as you stated, however it's now showing files under the `.git` folder.

Comment: Try this `export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND=‌​"find . \( -path '*/\.*' -type d -o -name .DS_Store \) -prune -o -type f -print -o -type l -print 2> /dev/null | sed s/^..//"`

Comment: It returns an empty result set now.